# Camera previewView lag under navigation controller hierarchy

Tags: swift, camera

I'm making an app with the following rough set up:

[image]

This is the camera view controller with a square camera view as you can see. The boxes below act as buttons to segue to another view controller via navigationController.push. After doing a few of those navigation controller pushes, the camera view get's laggy and eventually freezes.

I need to know if I'm doing this correctly. I currently set it such that when viewDidDissapear, the camera stops capturing. And when viewWillAppear, camera resumes capturing.

I've tried launching the other view controller in a modal view with a self.dismiss button, that didn't cause any lags in the camera view. So I believe it must be the navigation controller somehow affecting the live previewView of the camera.

Edit:

I have further narrowed it down and it seems like the lag is caused by interactive pop gesture.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by using background threading.

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
    print("This is run on the background queue")

    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        print("This is run on the main queue, after the previous code in outer block")
    }
}
```

turns out all I need to do is move the camera stop and resume observers to the background thread while moving all the UI elements including animation etc to the main thread.